# Converting a CFG with epsilons into a DPDA

Tags: context-free, automata, pushdown-automata, simulation

I have a CFG:

S -> $T$

T -> T+T|T-T|T/T|(T)|CX|I

X -> XX |C|N|_|@

C -> a|b|c|....|z|A|B|C|...|Z|_

N -> 0|1|2|....|9

I -> NI|N

Here @ means epsilon.

The above is a valid arithmetic expression in C++.

I have to convert this to a deterministic PDA (does not read @). I do know there exists an algorithm to convert it to NPDA but I have no clue how to go about converting it to DPDA. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Try to read the chapter about context-free languages in M.Sipser's [Theory of Computation](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=524279). The algorithm is explained there.

Comment: Welcome to Computer Science! Note that you can use LaTeX here to typeset mathematics in a more readable way. See [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/271/) for a short introduction.

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? We do not want to just hand you the solution; we want you to gain understanding. However, as it is we do not know what your underlying problem is, so we can not begin to help. See [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/1284/98) for tips on asking questions about exercise problems. If you are uncertain how to improve your question, why not ask around in [chat]?

Comment: Hint: instead of using a read-made algorithm, you can also try to come up with an equivalent DPDA on your own. What's the language here? (You can simplify the grammar by considering C and N terminal symbols.)

Comment: Hint: Have you tried to apply the standard algorithm. *Is* the result not determinstic? That single epsilon in the grammar does not have to translate into an epsilon-transition, if that's your concern!